# Fetching json from Mongo with Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to fetch a json object from the mongodb using meteor, but I have no clue why I’m unable to do so.

**I need it to be a JSON object only.**

One of the entries of the collection looks like this:

[Image taken from Meteor Dev Tools]

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxRmS.png

I’m trying to fetch the **value** part by passing the **name**.

**Code on front end:**

```
export default withTracker(() => {
  let aSub = Meteor.subscribe(‘allEntries’);
  return {
    aBoundaries: DataCollection.find({}).fetch()    
   }
})(Component Name);
```

**The Meteor Call Statement on front-end:**
dataFromDb = Meteor.call(‘functionToBeCalled’, ‘Sydney’);

**Server-side Code:**

```
Meteor.publish(‘allEntries’, function(){
    return DataCollection.find();
});

Meteor.methods({
   functionToBeCalled(aName){
      return DataCollection.find({name: aName});
   }
});
```

**Another of my questions is:**
Is there any way that we publish only all the names in the beginning and then publish the values on demand?

Thanks for your help in advance!

I have tried this as well, but it did not work:

```
functionToBeCalled(aName){
        var query = {};    
        query['name'] = aName;
        return DataCollection.find(query).fetch();
}
```

Comment: please ask the second question as seperate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with query.

`Collection.find()` returns data with cursor.

To get an array of objects, use `Collection.find().fetch()`. The jsons are returned as collection of array like `[{json1}, {json2}]`.

If there is a single document, you can access the json using `Collection.find().fetch()[0]`. Another alternative is to use findOne. Example - `Collection.findOne()`. This will return a single JSON object.

Comment: Hi, I tried this: return Collection.findOne({name: areaName}), but I still get it as undefined on the front-end. Is this using a Promise by any chance? Could that be the reason?  Thank you for your help on this!

Comment: can you please share the publications and subscrptions

Comment: I was able to make it work the way I wanted to... thanks to your answer. Will post the solution in the description itself.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use `Meteor.subscribe('allEntries')`, do not assign it to a variable.

`Meteor.subscribe` is asynchronous, it's best you ensure that your subscriptions are ready before you fetch data.

Log `DataCollection.find({}).fetch()` to your console

Check this official reference https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe.

Your second question isn't that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes here to look for the answer ~~~
So... I was able to make it work with this code on the server:

```
Meteor.methods({
    functionToBeCalled(aName){
        console.log(aName);
        return DataCollection.findOne({name: aName});
    }     
});
```

And this on the client:

```
Meteor.call('functionToBeCalled', nameToBePassed, (error,response) => {
            console.log(error, "error");
            console.log(response, "response"); //response here
})
```

Thanks for the help!